# Remove characters from the second string which are present in the first string

Tags: java, algorithm

I have written a program to remove the characters from the second string which are present in the first string. The complexity comes out to be BigO(n^2). Can the complexity be further reduced?

```
public class Tmp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "halloween";
        String s1 = "halcyon";
        char[] ss = s.toCharArray();
        char[] ss1 = s1.toCharArray();

        for(int i=0;i<ss.length;i++){
          for(int j=0;j<ss1.length;j++){
                if(ss1[j] == ss[i]){
                    ss1[j] = 'x'; //Replace the common char with x
                }
            }
         }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ss1));
    }
}
```

OUTPUT

```
 [x, x, x, c, y, x, x]
```

Comment: You can put your code on code review for better outcome. http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Yes, you can reduce it to `O(n log n)`.

Comment: Add all your chars of string1 to a set (`O(n)`). Next, for each char in string-2, use `contains()` on set-1 and set it to 'x' if it that char is there (`O(n)`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Convert first string into a Map. O(N)
2. iterate over other string and check if character present in Map from step 1.
   O(N) + O(1)

Total time complexity = O(N)

Here you have additional space complexity to store MAP.

Comment: Convert first string into a Map O(N) that's ok but when I iterate over the other string to check in the map that too will be O(N). Won't the total complexity will be O(N) + O(N)

Comment: Yes total complexity is O(N) + O(N) since there are two different loop, which will be 2*O(N). Here 2 is constant and for very large N we can ignore 2. Therefore, final complexity will be O(N).

Answer (score 2):

You can choose to convert second string to HashSet (if there are no duplicate letters in second string). Then check existence of each letter from first string in hashmap and remove if found.

O(N) complexity for traversing the String array and complexity of put/get in HashSet is almost O(1).

Comment: Better if you convert *first* string to map, then remove letters from second string that are found in map. Duplicate characters supported that way.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a boolean array of size 26 if all the characters in the source string are small letters.
Then scan the source string from start to end and update the boolean array if the character is present.
Then scan the target string and check with the boolean array if its present in source array or not.

The complexity will be equal to sum of both strings' length.

Comment: 'if the character is present' comes with a complexity O(n). Now total complexity will be O(n^2)

Answer (score 0):

Remove characters from input string that are present in mask string

```
public class RemoveCharacterFromFisrtStringWhichPInSecondString {

    public static void removeCharactersFromFirstString(String str1,String str2){
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(str1.toLowerCase());
        char maskArray[] = populateMaskArray(str2);
        for(int i=0;i<str1.length();i++){
            char ch = str1.toLowerCase().charAt(i);
            int index = sb.toString().indexOf(ch);
            if(maskArray[ch] == ch) {
                sb.deleteCharAt(index);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(sb.toString());
    }

    /**
     * Time Complexity: O(m) Where m is the length of mask string.
     */
    static char[] populateMaskArray(String mask) {
        char[] array = new char[256];
        for(int i = 0; i < mask.length(); i++) {
            array[mask.charAt(i)] = mask.charAt(i);
        }
        return array;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str1 = "India is country";
        String str2 = "in";
        removeCharactersFromFirstString(str1,str2);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Test{  
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String str,sbstr;
        
        System.out.println("Enter the first String : ");
        str = sc.nextLine();
        
        System.out.println("Enter the second String : ");
        sbstr = sc.nextLine();
        
        char [] c1str = str.toCharArray();
        char [] c2sbstr = sbstr.toCharArray();
       
        
            for(int j=0;j<c2sbstr.length;j++) {
                for(int i=0;i<c1str.length;i++) {

                if(c1str[i] == c2sbstr[j]) {
                    c1str[i] = 0;
                }    
            }
        }

        System.out.println("After removing the characters of second string from first string :");

        for(int i=0;i<c1str.length;i++) {
            System.out.print(c1str[i]); 
        }  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach could be using forLoop.

**Note: Below are Kotlin code**

```
val str1 = "computer"
val str2 = "cat"

var strBuilder = StringBuilder()

for (data in str1) {
    if (!str2.contains(data)) {
        strBuilder.append(data)
    }
}
println(strBuilder)
```

**Output: ompuer**

Answer (score -1):

```
 public static String removeCharAt(String s, int pos) {
      return s.substring(0, pos) + s.substring(pos + 1);
   }
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s1 = "India is great ";
        s1 = s1.toLowerCase();
        String s2="in";
        
        for (int i = 0; i < s1.length(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < s2.length(); j++) {
                if(s2.charAt(j) == s1.charAt(i)) {
                    s1 = removeCharAt(s1, i);
            }
        }               
    }
        System.out.println(s1);
        
}
```

Comment: This is not an answer as you have not reduced the complexity